# I am facing an attribute error in my python class code

Tags: class, object, attributes, turtle-graphics

here is my code that received an error.

```
from turtle import  Turtle
XCOR=[0,-20,-40]
MOVE_DISTANCE=20
class Snake:
    def __int__(self):
        self.snak=[]
        self.create_snake()

    def create_snake(self):
        for _ in XCOR:
            sna=Turtle("square")
            sna.color("white")
            sna.penup()
            sna.goto(XCOR[_],0)
            self.snak.append(sna)

    def move(self):
        for them in range(len(self.snak)-1,0,-1):
            newx=self.snak[them-1].xcor()
            newy=self.snak[them-1].ycor()
            self.snak[them].goto(newx,newy)
        self.snak[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)


snake=Snake()
snake.move()
```

Here is the error. I'm not sure why `Snake` object has no attribute `snak` given that it was defined in the `__init__`

```
 File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/snake game/snake.py", line 18, in move
    for them in range(len(self.snak)-1,0,-1):
                          ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'snak'
```

I was expecting the snake to move since this worked without creating a class. Here is my code without using a class, which works without errors.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time
screen=Screen()
screen.setup(width=600,height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.tracer(0)
screen.title("My snake game")
xcor=[0,-20,-40]
turtles=[]
for _ in range(0,3):
    turtle=Turtle("square")
    turtle.color("white")
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(xcor[_],0)
    turtles.append(turtle)
game=True
while game:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.6)
    for them in range(len(turtles)-1,0,-1):
        newx=turtles[them-1].xcor()
        newy=turtles[them-1].ycor()
        turtles[them].goto(newx,newy)
    turtles[0].forward(20)
    

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below should solve the issue.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.tracer(0)
screen.title("My snake game")
xcor = [0, -20, -40]
MOVE_DISTANCE = 20


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.snak = []
        self.create_snake()

    def create_snake(self):
        for _ in xcor:
            sna = Turtle("square")
            sna.color("white")
            sna.penup()
            sna.goto(_, 0)
            self.snak.append(sna)

    def move(self):
        for them in range(len(self.snak) - 1, 0, -1):
            new_x = self.snak[them - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.snak[them - 1].ycor()
            self.snak[them].goto(new_x, new_y)
        self.snak[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)


snake = Snake()

game = True
while game:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.6)
    snake.move()


screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `__init__` was spelled wrong (You did `__int__`)
So, your portion of init should look like:

```
    class Snake:
        def __init__(self):
            self.snak = []
            self.create_snake()
```

Just a suggestion, try making more descriptive names than `sna` or `snak`.